# how to ignore response fields dynamically in spring webflux

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-webflux, swagger-2.0

I have the below response modal generated from swagger2.0.

```
Generated(value = "org.openapitools.codegen.languages.SpringCodegen", date = "2022-08-17T22:02:01.513781100-05:00[America/Chicago]")

public class User implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @JsonProperty("id")
  private String id;
  @JsonProperty("name")
  private String name;
  @JsonProperty("city")
  private String city ;
  @JsonProperty("dateOfBirth")
  private String dateOfBirth;
}
```

when the get User returns the response I would like to  skip/Ignore the name and city and wants to return only id and dateOfBirth, how to use JsonIgnoreProperties while converting the response to  bodyToMono.

```
 public Mono<User> getUser(String userid) {
            return this.webClientConfig
                    .getWebClient()
                    .get()
                    .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path("/users/").path(userid).build())
                    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .retrieve()
                    .bodyToMono(User.class)
                    
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

used Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder
https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialize-json-unknown-properties